# React dragula package does not work on react latest version?

Tags: reactjs, react-dragula

I am using react latest version:**16.8.6**. I am try to integrate [react-dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/react-dragula) but this is not working. I am try same code which is mention on react-dragula documentation but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open github issue for that in the repo.

https://github.com/bevacqua/react-dragula/issues/34